# Malloc on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, malloc

I used to replace malloc routines on windows XP with nedmalloc
Very fast and better fragmentation management. (compiler is VS2008)

Now, Does it still relevant on windows7 ? 
I tested it on windows 7-x86, and sometimes the nedmalloc failed.
I will do soon some benchmarks to see the performance.

Do you know a better malloc replacement ?